# Adobe Flex / Flash Builder StageWebView not scaling to webpage width.

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I've been trying to render a webpage using the Adobe Flex / Flash builder StageWebView but it's not scaling the webpage to fit the phones screen dimension and basically cutting the right side of the webpage off. I've tried using

```
<meta name="viewPort" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;
            maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
```

This has not worked. Below is the Flex code I'm currently using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.media.StageWebView;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

        protected var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
        protected var openBrowser:Boolean = false; 


        protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
        {
            if (StageWebView.isSupported)
            {
                currentState = "normal";
                webView.stage = stage;
                webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,75,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
                webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE,onURLChange);    
                webView.loadURL("http://nealdrake.com/mls.html");    
                addEventListener(ViewNavigatorEvent.REMOVING,onRemove);
            }
            else {
                currentState = "unsupported";
                lblSupport.text = "StageWebView feature not supported";
            }    
        }

        protected function onURLChange(event:LocationChangeEvent):void
        {
            trace("URL change");
            // Uncomment the following line to load in the default browser instead... 
            //navigateToURL(new URLRequest(event.location));
        }

        protected function onRemove(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
        {
            this.webView.dispose();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="unsupported"/>
</s:states>

<s:Label id="lblSupport" includeIn="unsupported" width="95%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised it's cutting off the right hand side rather than the bottom, since that's what I'd expect from this:

`webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,75,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);`

You need to count for any X or Y offset in your width and height, like this:

`webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,75,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight - 75);`

It might be that your StageWebView is being initialised before your app's size is correct. Try adding a resize handler (listen for Event.RESIZE events on whatever component your code above is taken from) that sets the viewport again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @micspsm but the x y offset didn't work. I tried the Event.RESIZE but not sure if I've done it correctly. Screen shoot: [link]http://nealdrake.com/app-screenshoot.html [link]

Comment: Do you have control over the webpage that you're showing? If so, then this is more a matter of tweaking the CSS there to support mobile-sized dimensions, rather than anything you can achieve in Flex. It looks from your screenshot like the StageWebView is set up fine; it's the *content* that's the problem.